# Run C# File on the internet like a CGI File

Tags: c#, cgi

I have a Visual C# project on my computer and I would like my users to be able to interact with it through a web browser. I've done my research, and I understand that I will probably use CGI to do this.

However, while I have been able do this with .pl and .cpp files, i can't figure out how to to it with C sharp (.cs) files. Can anyone explain how I would do this?

EDIT: If there is an alternate solution wherein the webpage communicates my C# program as a back-end program, that works, too.

UPDATE: After cancelling with my hosting provider and setting up a home-based web server (windows), I finally got the C# file to run as CGI. Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you expose the functionality you're looking for using ASP.NET?

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience in C# far exceeds that in ASP.NET. For me, ASP.NET is not an option.

Comment: If you've done your research then you've undoubtedly come across this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cgi_csharp.aspx. Did this not work for you?

Comment: My web server can't run .aspx files (it is UNIX). Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Perhaps Mono would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to give us some context ... why wouldn't asp.net be an option? If you simply don't want to run in the context of IIS, you could simply write a windows service (and expose WCF services, or even raw sockets if that's what you need).

*edit:* in response to the recent comment about the server being UNIX, you can use MONO to run .net code on that server: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

You can either use something like [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) or if you'd prefer something different, you can look at [manos de mono](http://manosdemono.org/)

Comment: Apparently he's on Unix so IIS isn't an option.

Comment: I am taking a look at Mono now. I'll put up an update momentarily

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to install Mono

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume you have the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) compiler and runtime environment installed on your system.

[CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) takes place *entirely* via standard input and standard output. (This is one reason why it is so easy to write CGI scripts in Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. You just start reading standard input as usual, parse the variables, and write whatever output you want the client to see.) Don't forget that you're responsible for the [entire header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Output_format), including Mime type.

If you need something that performs faster than CGI's constant `fork(2)`+`execve(2)` re-starting your CLR over and over again, you can implement the [FastCGI protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) (at least, I didn't see a C# implementation on the Wikipedia page) yourself using sockets and start your CLR once only, so you have some reasonable performance. (I seem to remember Nat being passionate about the Mono process start time being "fast enough" to use it for interactive commands, so perhaps a lightly-loaded server won't have any trouble with plain old CGI interface.)